# MSDTC server not available

Tags: c#, msdtc

In my project, there are three components in same system. Component X is responsible for communication between Y and Z. X talks to Y using TCP and Z using WCF. Project uses SQL as database. A save interaction is facilitated by X and data should go to Y and Z components. In order to make sure that data is same across Y and Z we use CommitableTransaction. But we are seeing "MSDTC on server 'xxx' is unavailable" when X talks to Y and Distributed Transaction service is running.This happens once in a while and the only way to get my application working is restart the machine.  Non transaction calls between X and Y works fine. There are not any system log entries which could help figure out why this error is seen. Please suggest what can be checked.
Firewall (inbound\outbound), sql service are good.

Update1:
Code is something like below (Cannot provide working code since its a bit too much):

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;
options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TransactionTimeout);
CommittableTransaction saveTransac = new CommittableTransaction(options);
YInterface.Save(dataToSave, saveTransac);
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: There are tools for troubleshooting your MSDTC configuration - dtcping, if I recall correctly.